# I want close a CFSocket

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets

I have create a socket with CFSocket.
My program is correct but now i wanna close the socket (client side).
There is a istruction?
Thanks and sorry for my English XP

My code:

```
CFSocketRef s;
s = CFSocketCreate(
        NULL, 
        PF_INET,
        SOCK_STREAM, 
        IPPROTO_TCP, 
        kCFSocketDataCallBack, 
        AcceptDataCallback, 
        &context);
...
CFSocketConnectToAddress(s, address, 0);
...
//here i wanna close the socket
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`CFRelease(s)` should close and destroy the socket.

**edit** (after a bit more research)

According to [the documentation](http://tuvix.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001445-CH1g-CJBBHABC), the proper way to close the socket is by invalidating it (similar to how a Timer works, apparently).  So you'll want to do:

```
CFSocketInvalidate(s);  //closes the socket, unless you set the option to not close on invalidation
CFRelease(s);  //balance the create
```

Comment: You are sure that CFRealease close the socket?
I have test it but the socket doesn't close